# How to access file given to cilly in my CIL module

Tags: ocaml, static-analysis, c-intermediate-language

I have added a new feature to CIL(C Intermediate Language). I am able to execute my new module using

```
$cilly --dotestmodule --save-temps -D HAPPY_MOOD -o test test.c
```

Now, in my testmodule, I want to call Cfg.computeFileCFG for test.c file. But I don't know how to access test.c file in my module.

I tried using Cil.file. but it says "Unbound value Cil.file".

my code:

```
open Pretty
open Cfg
open Cil

module RD = Reachingdefs

let () = Cfg.computeFileCFG Cil.file

let rec fact n = if n < 2 then 1 else n * fact(n-1)
let doIt n = fact n

let feature : featureDescr =
  { fd_name = "testmodule";
    fd_enabled = ref false;
    fd_description = "simple test 1240";
    fd_extraopt = [];
    fd_doit = (function (f: file) -> ignore (doIt 10));
    fd_post_check = true;
  }
```

please tell me how to compute the Cfg for test.c file.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a CIL expert, but here are a few remarks:

- the CIL online documentation [states](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/api/Cil.html#TYPEfile) that `Cil.file` is an Ocaml type. Passing a **type** as an argument to a **function** is probably not what you want to do here;
- it seems like the `fd_doit` function in your feature descriptor takes the file you are looking to process as its argument `f`;
- according to the [Cilly](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/cilly.html) manual, the type of `f` is `Cil.file`. Conveniently, this [seems](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/api/Cfg.html) to be the type of the argument required by the function `computeFileCFG`.

Hopefully you can take it from here. Good luck!